# How to check auth in other Rails Engines using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

The Rails architecture of my application is one application with many Rails Engines. One my engines deals with auth, wrapping [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

What I haven't figured out appropriately is how to get -all- my other Engines to check for actions.

Coming from Grails, I would have done this [with a Filter](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters) like:

```
checkUserCookie(controller:'*', action:'*') {
        before = { }
}
```

How to do something comparable in Rails? The only solution that I found is in my AuthEngine, to subclass ActionController::Base and add my before_filter there. Then I would be required to inherit from this in all my other engines.  This seems like it is too round-a-bout.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that I want [to use Rack with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html) for this as this part of core Rails installation. There is an excellent [Rack Middleware RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware) that explains how to begin to do this.